# Opening GIMP with Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line, gimp, shoes

So I'm making a Ruby Shoes application and I want to be able to open a file with GIMP from it. So far I've tried running `gimp` from ruby and all it does is return the command line message:

```
gimp
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/:/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/a/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/a/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/a/.rvm/bin:/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Trying to open an application with `open -a GIMP somefile.jpg` from within ruby just gives me an error window saying `GIMP cannot be opened because of a problem.`

EDIT:
Okay, so I'm here with a friend of mine and we're working on it together and we found out something that makes me angry like the hulk. I made a small program that still has the same error.

```
Shoes.app width: 640, height: 756, title: 'Eine' do
  para `source ~/.bashrc; GIMP PRfyS.jpg`
end
```

What's stupid about it? I can go into my Terminal and type `ruby -e " Shoes.app width: 640, height: 756, title: 'Eine' do para source ~/.bashrc; GIMP PRfyS.jpg end` and it works. (backticks are removed for stackoverflow formatting)

Comment: Take a look at [Ruby's Open3 library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html).

Comment: It sounds like your copy of GIMP is corrupt. Can you open it manually?

Comment: GIMP is not corrupt. I can open it by clicking the icon and through the command line. I just can't use Ruby to open it.

Comment: I'll try it out and see if it works.

Comment: Neither `open` nor `gimp` works.

Comment: We *REALLY* need to see how you're trying to do it by seeing your code, not by a quote of the string you're using with your sub-shell. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what exactly you want to do. if you just want to a button to launch GIMP then this is how I'd do it

```
Shoes.app do
    button "open gimp" do
        spawn 'gimp PRfyS.jpg'
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it in a little bit. I've never even heard of the spawn method.

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Can you verify if it works for you?

Comment: It's working fine for me. Your problem is likely with ruby or gimp.